# MySQL: Move data from multiple rows to one row based on column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table in the following format. This is an output from a program that I run and I cannot change it.

```
+---+------------------------+
|   |  A    B   C   D    E   |
+---+------------------------+
|   | model amz wmt abt tgt  |
| 1 | c3000 100              |
| 2 | c3000     200          |
| 3 | c3000         150      |
| 4 | c3000              125 |
| 5 | A1234              135 |
| 6 | A1234     105          |
+---+------------------------+
```

I want to move all the rows into one single row based on the value in column 1 i.e model. The caveat is that the blank rows are not actually blank and contain a null character

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
+---+-----------------------+
|   |  A    B   C   D    E  |
+---+-----------------------+
|   | model amz wmt abt tgt |
| 1 | c3000 100 200 150 125 |
| 2 | A1234 200 105     135 |
+---+-----------------------+
```

I tried using

> ```
> select model,group_concat(wmt),group_concat(amz)     
> from table_name
> group by model
> ```

And the output that I get is riddled with commas

```
+---+----------------------------------+
|   |  A                  B            |
+---+----------------------------------+
|   | model  amz          wmt          |
| 1 | c3000  ,,,,100,,,,   ,,,200,,,,  |
| 2 | A1234  ,,200,,,,,,  ,105,,,,,,   |
+---+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: You get the commas because you store and empty string `''` where there's a missing value. If you used `NULL` for a missing value, group_concat() would ignore the NULLs.

Comment: @BillKarwin The software from which I load the data on to MySQL sends emtpy strings and that's why I cannot use NULL.

Comment: See function [NULLIF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TRIM and IF to convert blank values to null.

```
SELECT 
    model,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(TRIM(wmt) = '', NULL, wmt)),
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(TRIM(amz) = '', NULL, amz))
FROM
    table_name
GROUP BY model
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   model,
   MIN(amz) AS amz,
   MIN(wmt) AS wmt,
   MIN(abt) AS abt,
   MIN(tgt) AS tgt
FROM
   table_name
GROUP BY
   model
```